# Does every metrizable space have point-countable base?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Just as the title explains: Does every metrizable space have point-countable base? Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Point-countable = First countable?

Comment: No. Point countable means that each point belongs to only countable many members of the family. first countable $\le$ point countable.

Comment: What does $\leq$ mean? Weaker? Stronger?

Comment: Metrizable what?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: first countable is weaker than point countable. If the space has one countable base, it is easy to see it is first countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is a standard consequence of A. H. Stone's theorem that every open cover of a metrizable space has a locally finite and $\sigma$-discrete open refinement. This implies that every metrizable space has a $\sigma$-locally finite base, i.e. a base $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{B}_n$ such that each $\mathcal{B}_n$ is locally finite.

The idea is to extract for each $n$ a locally finite open refinement $\mathcal{B_n}$ of the collection of all balls of radius $1/n$ and to show that $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{B}_n$ is a base. Indeed: if $B(x,r)$ is a ball and $n$ is so large that $\frac{2}{n} \lt r$ then every element $U \in \mathcal B_n$ containing $x$ must be contained in $B(x,r)$ since $\operatorname{diam}(U) \leq 2/n$. Clearly, every point is contained in at most countably many elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

See e.g. Engelking, Theorem 4.4.1 and Corollary 4.4.4 or Munkres, Step 2 of the proof of the Nagata-Smirnov metrization theorem 40.3 and Lemma 39.2 for more details.

Comment: Note also that a locally finite collection is point finite, and a countable union of point finite collections is point-countable.

Comment: See here for a short proof of a key point: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-020-02/S0002-9939-1969-0236876-3/S0002-9939-1969-0236876-3.pdf